# Assigning variable names to an output graph in R

Tags: r, variables, graph, filenames, assign

I am a new user of R statistics. I am having a huge `for` loop, of multiple massive files, the loop ends up giving me the result of a graph.

Everything is working fine, except with the output file names.
what do I want exactly to do?

I am using

```
data1 <- read.csv("filepath/filename", header=TRUE, sep=",")
data2 <- read.csv("filepath/filename", header=TRUE, sep=",")
data3 <- read.csv("filepath/filename", header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

and so on... to read my files.

I want the output graph file name to contain the name of the data files and columns from which it was generated. For example:

```
graph1-data1-data3-columnE.pdf
```

**Important note:** all the files I am reading have exactly the same column names and number.

What command should I use to do this?

Comment: You could use ?paste() to build the filename for your plot.

Comment: Hello EDi.
 I treid to use the paste funciton but i can't find the command to tell R to copy file names, can you show me a sample of the command you are talking about?
Thanks

Comment: In reading the files you typed manually the filenames. You need them stored somewhere in an object. Either again manually or use functions like ?list.files.

Comment: aaaalright, now I already did this yesterday,but i have been trying the whole day to write a command to get this working, like for example i stored all file names in a file called "fnames" and i already have the column names saved as in the "names.data1" function. the output command is going to be? pdf (filepath(paste(..............) what? i am not getting the paste command itself. Sorry but, i'm having hard time with this command!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve it using `paste` as @EDi pointed out, `paste0` or `sprintf`. I prefer the latter as it has very clean syntax. In the following example `%i` (for integer) is replaced with the values of `i`, `d1` and `d2` and `%s` (for string) is replaced with the value of `col`.

```
for(i in 1:n){
    ...
    d1 <- 1    # Index of the first data file
    d2 <- 3    # Index of the second data file
    col <- "E" # Column name
    ...
    outfile <- sprintf("Graph%i-data%i-data%i-column%s.pdf", i, d1, d2, col)
    pdf(outfile)
    ...
    dev.off()
}
```

#### Some general advice

Whenever you find yourself creating objects named `data1`, `data2`, `data3` and so on, you are essentially faking a list of objects. Make a proper list instead and your syntax will be more compact, easier to read and write.

```
# List all files named `data###.csv`, where ### is a number
my.files <- dir(".", "data[0-9]+\\.csv")

# Load all files in one go
my.data <- lapply(my.files, read.csv, header=TRUE, sep=",")

# Calculate the thing you are interested in        
n <- length(my.files)
for(i in 1:n){
    for(j in 1:n){
        # Do stuff
        pdf(sprintf("Graph-%i-%i.pdf", i, j))
        plot(my.data[[i]], my.data[[j]])
        dev.off()
    }
}
```